# What's faster DOM Insertion or Manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Am I better to move a node I sent down form the server or to insert it?

I'm using jQuery (1.4) but would like to know for both jQuery and JS in general. In this case the node is small with only one child. But what if it were a large list?

What

large list 1 = 200 li nodes

large list 2 = 1000 li nodes

**Example:**

***Insertion:***

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="box></div>
</div>

$('#box').before($('<ul id="list"><li>...</ul>'));
```

vs

***Manipulation:***

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="box></div>
</div>
<ul id="list"><li>...</ul>

$('#list').insertBefore($('#box'));
```

Comment: `But what if it were a large list?` how large?

Comment: +1 @c0mrade - it is very important to define "large" or "small" or "fast" when we need to define any performance metrics

Comment: I don't understand what ‘manipulation’ vs. ‘insertion’ is supposed to mean in this question. If you have a Node object already, inserting it into the document is manipulation, and will move it from where it was if it was already in the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client is going to spend a lot more time rendering your new items than it will actually putting them into the DOM. I would recommend you remove the #list from the DOM entirely, add the items to it, and then put it back into the DOM. At least for large data sets.

Even then, the repaint could be slow, especially on IE with complex CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The two are the same.  If you look at the source, you can see that 'insertBefore' is merely mapped to 'before'.

REF for 'insertBefore': http://gist.github.com/277432#LID4389

REF for 'before': http://gist.github.com/277432#LID4088

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve performance would be to provide a context for the insertion.

When doing `$('#list').insertBefore($('#box'));` , you should provide the context node if you have it, rather than research the entire tree. Something similar to

```
var myWapper = getWrapperFromEventOrWhereEverYouMightHaveIt();

//more code doing fancy things here

$(myWrapper, '#list').insertBefore($('#box'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your *entire* list is updated when you get data from the server then you should have a structure that resembles something like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
  <div id="box></div>
</div>
```

Then you can have all the nodes sent as just a list of li elements and then do something like so:

```
$("list")[0].innerHTML = xhr.responseText // response text is of form 
                                          //<li>item</li><li>item</li>... etc
```

Tests have shown that innerHTML is faster then append, insert (before and after) etc.
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html